# Shift operators - operands must be convertible to an integer primitive?

Tags: java, java-8, bit-shift

I'm preparing myself to a Java exam, and I'm reading "OCA Java SE 8 Programmer Study Guide (Exam 1Z0-808)". In operators section I found this sentence:

> Shift Operators: A shift operator takes two operands whose type must be
>   convertible to an integer primitive.

I felt odd to me so I tested it with long:

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         long test = 3147483647L;
         System.out.println(test << 1);

     }
}
```

and it worked, no compiler errors and result is correct. Does the book has a bug or am I misunderstanding the quote from the book?

Comment: The JLS defines integral type as _"The numeric types are the integral types byte, short, int, long, and char,..."_ and for the shift operator _"It is a compile-time error if the type of each of the operands of a shift operator, after unary numeric promotion, is not a primitive integral type."_

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The shift operators `>>` and `<<` are defined in [JLS section 15.19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19). Quoting:

> Unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1) is performed on each operand separately. (Binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is not performed on the operands.)
>
> **It is a compile-time error if the type of each of the operands of a shift operator, after unary numeric promotion, is not a primitive integral type**.

When talking about "integer primitive", the book is really talking about "primitive integral type" (defined in [JLS section 4.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)):

> The values of the integral types are integers in the following ranges:
>
> - For byte, from -128 to 127, inclusive
> - For short, from -32768 to 32767, inclusive
> - For int, from -2147483648 to 2147483647, inclusive
> - For long, from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807, inclusive
> - For char, from '\u0000' to '\uffff' inclusive, that is, from 0 to 65535

Answer (score 4):

They're using `integer` not in the Java `int` fashion, but rather as "integer type instead of floating point or other type". Java's `long` is an integer too, it's just a 64-bit wide integer.